# Auto mounting other partitions in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, fstab, automounting

I am using Arch Linux. Is there a way to automount other NTFS or Ext partitions automatically without configuring them in `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: Like in ubuntu i never used to mention them in fstab they were auto mounted by a simple app.

Comment: If they are partitions, not external devices, they *should* be added to `/etc/fstab`. If you want to mount them on demand (ie., only when you try and access them), then add the `noauto` field...

Comment: @jasonwryan i know about fstab bt i want them auto detected and mounted automatically.

Comment: If they are *internal* then you put them in `/etc/fstab`. If you are talking about *external* drives, then use a udev tool...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/gnome-disk-utility/ which is a GUI application that will allow you to generate an fstab entry automatically.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do that, of course, but why would you want to? That's what the `fstab` file is *for*.

Some ideas:

- Create a systemd mount or automount (or just a plain startup script that runs `mount`).
- Use a crontab to run mount.
- Have a start-up script in your desktop-environment.
- Find a tool in the official repos or AUR that do that for you (I don't have a recommendation).
- Insert an evil hack wherever you choose.